# Facebook login via Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have successfully logged in using facebook popup at the same page.

I have checked the response `response.status === 'connected'` and it has truly got true.

```
 $('#sign_in').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        FB.login(function(response){

        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

        function statusChangeCallback(response) {

            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
            } else {
                // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                // they are logged into this app or not.
            }
        }


    });
```

Now,the question is, how can I actively login with devise?
I have already set the route as:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

And I have added the controller of callbacks:

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook

    puts "FACEBOOK CALLBACK"
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

But I've noticed that the callback was not called, please advice!

**EDIT:**
Here is the basic settings of the test app at facebook:
[image]

Comment: Have you set the OAuth redirect URI for your facebook app?

Comment: Kindly check EDIT above